# Showing that the unsigned area bounded by plane curve $\gamma$ is $-\frac1{4\pi}\oint_\gamma\oint_\gamma\vec{dx}\cdot\vec{dy}\log(\|x-y\|^2)$

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a curve in the plane. I wish to show:
$$A=\frac{-1}{4\pi}\oint_\gamma\oint_\gamma\overrightarrow{dx}\cdot\overrightarrow{dy}\log\left(\|x-y\|^2\right),$$

where here $A$ is the *unsigned* area bounded by $\gamma$. For instance, the unsigned area of the lemniscate is strictly positive whereas its signed area is zero.

[image]

- I believe this formula is true because I have checked it for rectangles and ellipses, and numerically for a variety of other curves. Nevertheless I haven't been able to prove it myself or find a proof.
- I believe Stokes' theorem is not helpful because I would guess proofs based on it would lead to signed area.
- The physical motivation for this comes from thinking about electromagnetism in 1+1 dimensions, which might be a helpful starting point.

Comment: Looking for some starting point for how this formula could come about, I began thinking about integration in polar coordinates (integration through some angle sweeps an area out, just as for a fixed $y$ in the diagram, the length $\| x - y \|$ sweeps out area). Integration of a polar function $r = f(\theta)$ is of the form $\int \frac{1}{2}r^2 d\theta$. I also see a length squared in your formula. The only thing is that integration in polar coordinates is from some origin. Here, the origin is on the curve, and the outside integral constantly shifts the origin along the curve. This is just a

Comment: remark, attempting to find some starting point (from the basis of multivariable calculus - because area is such an important quantity - you'd think or hope this formula has a proof in that domain). But these remarks may be completely wrong  or not useful for this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is true when $\gamma$ is a positively oriented simple closed curve bounding some Jordan domain $\Omega$.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the integral at hand. Identify Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and introduce complex coordinates $x,y$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\vec{x} = (x_1,x_2) & \leftrightarrow & x = x_1 + x_2 i\\
\vec{y} = (y_1,y_2) &\leftrightarrow  & y = y_1 + y_2 i
\end{cases}$$
Let $z = y - x$. For any $\vec{\rho} = (\rho_1,\rho_2) \leftrightarrow \rho = \rho_1 + i\rho_2 \in \mathbb{C}$, we will use the notation $\Omega + \rho$ and $\gamma + \rho$ to denote the image of $\Omega$ and $\gamma$ under translation $\vec{\rho}$.

In terms of complex coordinates, we have
$d\vec{x} \cdot d\vec{y} = \frac12 \left(dx d\bar{y} + dy d\bar{x}\right)$. This leads to

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} 
&= -\frac{1}{8\pi} \int_{\gamma \times \gamma} \log(z\bar{z}) (dx d\bar{y} + dyd\bar{x})
= -\frac{1}{4\pi}\Re \left[\int_{\gamma\times\gamma} \log(z\bar{z}) dx d\bar{y}\right]\\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi}\Re\left[\int_{x \in \gamma} \left(\int_{z \in \gamma - x}\log(z\bar{z}) d\bar{z}\right) dx\right]
\end{align}\tag{*1}
$$
Apply [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem) (the version for complex coordinates) to the inner integral, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi}\Re\left[\int_{x\in\gamma} \left(\int_{z \in \Omega - x}
\left(\frac{dz}{z} + \frac{d\bar{z}}{\bar{z}}\right)\wedge d\bar{z}\right) dx\right]\\
&=  \frac{1}{4\pi}\Re\left[\int_{x\in\gamma} \left(
\int_{z\in \Omega - x}\frac{d\bar{z} \wedge dz}{z}
\right) dx\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi}
\Re\left[\int_{x\in\gamma} \left(
\int_{y\in \Omega}\frac{d\bar{y} \wedge dy}{y-x}
\right) dx\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi}
\Re\left[
\int_{y\in\Omega}\left(\int_{x\in\gamma}\frac{dx}{y-x}\right) d\bar{y} \wedge dy
\right]
\end{align}
$$
By [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula), we have $$\int_{x\in\gamma}\frac{dx}{y-x} = -2\pi i\quad\text{ for } y \in \Omega$$ As a result,
$$\begin{align}\mathcal{I} 
&= \frac{1}{4\pi} \Re\left[ \int_{y \in \Omega} (-2\pi i)(2i dy_1 \wedge dy_2 )\right]
= \Re\left[ \int_{y \in \Omega} dy_1 \wedge dy_2 \right]\\
&= \Re\left[\verb/Area/(\Omega)\right] = \verb/Area/(\Omega)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Update** - Generalization to non-simple closed curves.

For non-simple closed curve $\gamma$ and $y \not\in \gamma$, let $W(\gamma;y)$ be the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $\gamma$ around $y$. We have following generalization of Cauchy integral formula:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dx}{y-x} = -2\pi i W(\gamma;y)\tag{*2}$$

When $\gamma$ satisfies following conditions:

1. $\gamma$ can be decomposed into finitely many curve segments, the segments either completely coincides or their interior (as a curve segment) are disjoint from each other.
2. $\gamma$ divides $\mathcal{C}\setminus \gamma$ into finitely many connected  components, the boundaries of these components are finite combinations of curve segments from step $1$.

We can break any contour integral over $\gamma$ to integral combinations of contour integrals over boundaries of connected components in step $2$.
We can apply Stoke's theorem to the individual components and recombine the results.

Apply this procedure to inner contour integral in $(*1)$ and with help of $(*2)$, we obtain:

$$
\mathcal{I}
= \frac{1}{4\pi}
\Re\left[\int_{x\in\gamma} \left(
\int_{y\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\gamma}\frac{W(\gamma;y)}{y-x} d\bar{y} \wedge dy
\right) dx\right]
= \int_{y\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\gamma} W(\gamma;y)^2 dy_1 \wedge dy_2$$

Recall winding number is constant over each connected component. If $\Omega_1, \ldots, \Omega_m$ are the connected components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\gamma$ with non-zero winding numbers and $W_i$ is the winding number for $\Omega_i$,
we can rewrite last expression as

$$\mathcal{I} = \sum_{i=1}^m W_i^2 \verb/Area/(\Omega_i)$$

The integral $\mathcal{I}$ is simply a weighted sum of the areas of connected components and the weight equals to the square of corresponding winding number.

In the special case where all $|W_i| \le 1$, above formula simplifies to

$$\mathcal{I} = \sum_{i=1}^m \verb/Area/(\Omega_i)$$

$\mathcal{I}$ becomes the unsigned area of those connected components whose winding number is non-zero.

Comment: Possibly connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281140